# Attempting to use inline-block to center div element, but not working

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <div class="w3-card-8 w3-dark-grey" style="width:40%">
    <div class="w3-card-8 w3-dark-grey">
      <div class="w3-container w3-center">
        <h3>Featured Event</h3>
        <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/xaqqs9.png" alt="Rock n Swap Poster" style="width:80%">
        <h5>Rock 'N Swap - August 28th</h5>
        <a href="/events">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-green">Learn More!</button>
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="w3-card-8 w3-dark-grey" style="width:40%">
    <div class="w3-card-8 w3-dark-grey">
      <div class="w3-container w3-center">
        <h3>Featured Event</h3>
        <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/xaqqs9.png" alt="Rock n Swap Poster" style="width:80%">
        <h5>Rock 'N Swap - August 28th</h5>
        <a href="/events">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-green">Learn More!</button>
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note: tried to make a CSS element with display:inline-block, but it keeps appearing underneath the first div. I want them to align side by side... And eventually be able to add more divs next to each other.

Comment: how about positing your css as well. Also, centering on a page, another div?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You need to post your CSS. See [mcve]

Comment: I want to center these div elements within another main div container. Dont have css specific to this code because it wasnt working. I just want to align these 2 divs within my main div

Comment: try floating your desired 2 elements both left inside the div as well as making sure their combined size including padding is not larger than the size of their containing div @user3490784